# Why do spammers use CELESTRON NEXTAR 6SE?

Tags: spam, spam-prevention, spamming

I am running a website for a volunteer organization that hosts an annual event. There is a form where people can volunteer to bring items for the event.

All too frequently I get spam from users across the globe that enter things like this:

> Country - 1: Australia
>
> Material - 1: CELESTRON NEXTAR 6SE
>
> Country - 2: Australia
>
> Material - 2: C8 Newton
>
> Country - 3: Australia
>
> Material - 3: ETX 125EC
>
> Country - 4: Australia
>
> Material - 4: ETX 125EC
>
> Country - 5: Australia
>
> Material - 5: CELESTRON NEXTAR 6SE

I don't really care about the country, but what is it with the telescope stuff? Is there some hidden meaning behind all this or is it some astronomy group that moonlights as spammers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spammers sppam for everything: medication, software, even astronomy. If there's a way to make a buck by spamming there will be spammers who spam to do just that.

Comment: Thanks John. Amazing what people get paid to do?

Answer (score 3):

Fmz, you… kind of inadvertedly advertised, that telescope to me ***right now***.

And maybe you searched for it on google, and maybe you visited an online shop that sells it.

So I suppose they have a point about that. Not a direct sale, *more of a branding thing*.

Comment: More of a negative branding thing in all honesty! If I see somebody spamming a particular product I'd say I'm less likely to convert than if I were to stumble across it myself.

Comment: Yes, on a **conscious level**, that's true. But I can't help the fact **I had no idea** there was telescope by that name, and **now I know**, and sooner or later **this will come out somewhere** in my writing or my talking... maybe even while talking about spamming.

Comment: «I don't care what they call me as long as they mention my name» —George M. Cohan (one of advertising axioms)

Comment: Well, that's just you. :)

Comment: ***UPDATE:*** I was in a mall the other day, northern Italy, looking for a smartphone to gift and... there I noticed them: pretty compact telescopes of that brand. Kinda neat, too. The droplet is digging: deeper and deeper into my brain, still didn't got one, but a desire is forming. Evidently I'm in the target demographic... and **spam is really a twisted craft**.

Comment: Haha, interesting that you noticed - and more interesting that you remembered this question! Well spotted. :-)

Comment: ***UPDATE #2:*** Since the last update I couldn't help but noticing that brand again 3 or 4 times around town, they're definitely expanding. My girlfriend suddenly decided she needed a telescope. I *struggled* not to say that word. I insanely suggested to buy the first I could notice of *a different* brand. This conversion didn't go trough, phew. I hope this cheap one we got doesn't break up or proves unworthy, otherwise I'll definitely end up getting her a *********.